# AngularJS not selecting the user-selection in a select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I hope you guys are doing very good in your life. I am trying to make a select box with a default selection and allowing user to change the selection if they want.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ibnyusrat/jf5gggj0/

I am using this line to write the select box and its options:

```
<select name="defaultQuality" ng-model="CreatePlayer.form.defaultQuality" ng-options="item.quality as item.label for item in CreatePlayer.getQualities() track by item.quality">
     <option style="display:none" value="">Select a quality</option>
</select>
```

And the function that produces the options is:

```
CreatePlayer.getQualities = function(){
    var c = Array();
    c[0] = {quality:"SD",label:"SD"};
    if(CreatePlayer.form.p1080){
      c[1]={quality:"HD",label:"HD"}
    }
    return c;
 }
```

If I remove this line:

```
 CreatePlayer.form.defaultQuality = {quality:"SD",label:"SD"};
```

It does seem to work. The issue is, if I don't define a default option, the select works as it should. But the moment I define a default option, and then I programmatically add an option to the list, changing selection causes the select box to revert to the empty value for the firs time, but in all the following times it works. So the user actually has to select the option twice to get it to recognize it.

Am I making a very obvious mistake here? Please help.

Comment: Just remove `track by item.quality` and you should be fine

Comment: @AlonEitan As it can be tested on the JSFiddle, removing the track by option results in not having a default selection, which is what I already wrote that the script does seem to work without a default option.

Comment: So something like this maybe? https://jsfiddle.net/jf5gggj0/1/

Comment: Its perfect, how did you do that? Please post an answer and I will select it as the answer, and please also provide some details of how you did that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so first thing first - This is a working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/jf5gggj0/1/

The first thing I did is to change `CreatePlayer.getQualities` from a function into an array. Why? Because it's much better performances-wise - Instead of calling this function on every digest cycle (Which happens a lot), Angular can now just track changes on the object.

**Before:**

```
CreatePlayer.getQualities = function(){
    var c = Array();
    c[0] = {quality:"SD",label:"SD"};
    if(CreatePlayer.form.p1080){
      c[1]={quality:"HD",label:"HD"}
    }
    return c;
}
```

**After:**

```
CreatePlayer.getQualities = [{quality:"SD",label:"SD"}];
```

Next thing I did was to add `ng-change="CreatePlayer.enableHD()"` on the checkbox, which call the following function when you check/uncheck it:

```
CreatePlayer.enableHD = function() {
    if(CreatePlayer.form.p1080){
        CreatePlayer.getQualities.push({quality:"HD",label:"HD"});
      return;
    }
    var a =  CreatePlayer.getQualities.map(function(e) { return e.quality; }).indexOf('HD');
    if( a !== -1 ) {
        CreatePlayer.getQualities.splice(a, 1);
    }
};
```

What this function does is that it check if the box is checked (`if(CreatePlayer.form.p1080){ ... }`), and if it does, it adds the `HD` option to the select options, otherwise, it removes it:

```
var a =  CreatePlayer.getQualities.map(
   // return an array of the "quality" values, and keeps the same indexes as the original "getQualities" array
   function(e) { return e.quality; }
).indexOf('HD'); // Return the position of "HD" in order to remove it from the original "getQualities" array
```

And then I use the `a` (Which holds the **position** of "HD") variable to remove the element from the array:  `CreatePlayer.getQualities.splice(a, 1);`

The last thing was to change the `ngOptions` expression.

**Before:**

```
ng-options="item.quality as item.label for item in CreatePlayer.getQualities() track by item.quality"
```

**After:**

```
ng-options="item as item.label for item in CreatePlayer.getQualities"
```

I removed the `track by item.quality` because the `ngModel` of the select is **referencing to an *element*** inside the `CreatePlayer.getQualities` array in the controller: `CreatePlayer.form.defaultQuality = CreatePlayer.getQualities[0];` so now Angular manage the binding of the select value for you, and that's why it's not getting reset avery time you change the elements inside the `getQualities` array.

Well, that's about it :)

But just remember - **Avoid as much as possible binding functions to the view, only bind members of the scope (properties/objects)**.

Comment: One word: Brilliant! Thank you so very much for taking the time you took and for all the discomfort this might have caused. Thank you once again! :)

Comment: It was my pleasure :) Thanks for accepting my answer

Comment: One issue though.. previously, the value in CreatePlayer.form.defaultQuality used to be either SD or HD and so I was testing against these values in the PHP, now, the value of the select is the entire object, like  `{"quality":"SD","label":"SD"}`. (https://jsfiddle.net/jf5gggj0/2/) Do you think I can write it so it gives the value like it previously did?

Comment: It was because I changed `item.quality as item.label` to `item as item.label` (I personally prefer to work with the actual object). Don't forget to change `CreatePlayer.form.defaultQuality = CreatePlayer.getQualities[0];` to `CreatePlayer.form.defaultQuality = CreatePlayer.getQualities[0].quality;` as I did in the fiddle in my last comment (You can also cahnge it to `CreatePlayer.form.defaultQuality = 'SD';` if you prefer)

Comment: Got it! Thank you very very much for the help. I owe you! :) Thanks again! :)

Comment: For some reason it keeps on adding data type to the string when I read it in PHP. So instead of SD, it says string:SD. This doesn't happen if I add track by, but then adding track by doesn't allow me to set a default option.

Comment: @MuhammadbinYusrat Not sure why do you need it via PHP (Aince Angular should be a pure js SPA), but try this: https://jsfiddle.net/jf5gggj0/4/ - And angular add this "string" thing because it helps it to determine the type of the value (String/Number/Object) - This is something internal that angular add by itself